Read-update-write a cell's value in Google bigtable with optimistic locking
In BigTable's data writing example, "Conditionally write a value" support to do some predefined operation, like increase. This can avoid data be override by distributed writing operations
Is it doable to use Read-update-write style to load the original value with version in bigtable, update the value in client side, write the updated value back with read version check to make sure the write operation will not override value that written after its read?

if you use ReadModifyWrite, Bigtable will take a lock to prevent one from overwriting a value written by some other process between their read and write similar to your Conditional Write comment.
If you're trying to increment a numeric value, it might be better to use https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/aggregates which doesn't require locking.

Based on the doc https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigtable/latest/Google-Cloud-Bigtable-ReadModifyWriteRule , ReadModifyWrite supports append and increment. But it doesn't support other modification. If we keep bytes in Bigtable and using a fully self defined code to write the update logic, it seems ReadModifyWrite doesn't support.
